# AngularJS run() block promise end

Tags: angularjs

How can i make sure that the promise I activated is finished in  `run()` block , before the AngularJS keep with its calling order of directives and etc?

This is what I already tried:

```
app.run(['initService', function(initService) {
 initService.init().then(() => {return true});
}
```

I want that the AngularJS continue its calling order only after the return true is happening.

thank you

Comment: do you have any routing (`ngRoute` / `ui.router`)? You can **resolve** a function call before the page is even loaded, and therefore any directives/controllers executed

Comment: i know about this option but i need to promise end before another promise start so i thout that with app.run it will work, so in the app.run the first promise run and in the ngRoute resolver the second happen

Comment: In javascript all are async event. It wont wait for response. You can use logic in controller to handle this